# Why does beautiful-soup change the html?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML file. I am trying to open it and read the contents as

```py
with open("M_ALARM_102.HTML", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
```

when I print the contents in the above command it prints perfectly. But when I pass the contents to BeautifulSoup and print the soup it changes the HTML code

```py
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, html.parser)
    print(soup)
```

here is the output from BeautifulSoup

```
ÿþ&lt;html&gt;

&lt;head&gt;

&lt;meta charset="UTF-8"&gt;

&lt;title&gt;ARRÊT SERVOS&lt;/title&gt;

&lt;style type="text/css"&gt;
```

I am not getting why it is doing this. I need to extract 3 tags from it but it keeps giving `None` as output.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the parser used by BeautifulSoup did not recognize that file as html.

I see two "strange" characters in that output: `ÿþ`. They look like something added the BOM ([byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) to the file, while the parser expected valid utf-8.
There is a good chance that this is the problem.

One way to fix the BOM problem is to open the file in notepad, and save it as UTF-8. Notepad is pretty good at doing this kind of stuff.

You might also be able to fix it by opening the file in python as utf-16, using `with open("M_ALARM_102.HTML", "r", encoding="utf-16") as f:`. Note that here you specify the encoding directly (see more from [python documentation about unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)).

Note that I did not personally try the latter approach, so I am not sure it will actually remove the BOM -- the best option is still to not introduce it at all in your workflow.

Comment: Thanks @rob your both solutions worked. I think that strange character was an issue when I opened the file in notepad there wasn't any strange character, although I saved it as guided and it worked like magic.

Answer (score 1):

&lt is < this symbol and &gt is > this symbol. İt is for security to protect web site by XSS ( Cross Site Scripting ) attacks.

Comment: okay. but when I print `soup.h1`  it returns empty. How do I get that solved?

Comment: Because when developer uses &lt and &gt that time &lt h1 &gt isn`t HTML tag, it is just a text.